# Cron job with an alias

Tags: ubuntu, cron, meltano

While I work on setting up Meltano, I'd like to create a simple cron job to schedule my Pipelinewise tap/target on my Ubuntu server.  Transferwise references using the following crontab:

```
*/5 *   * * * pipelinewise run_tap --tap microserv_1 --target redshift # Sync every 5 minutes
```

I am new to Linux and unsure how to include the alias for pipelinewise.  I am running it in a docker container and always start with:

cd pipelinewise

alias pipelinewise="$(pwd)/bin/pipelinewise-docker"

How do I incorporate this in to the crontab?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Omit the alias:

*/5 *   * * *  /home/ubuntu/pipelinewise/bin/pipelinewise-docker run_tap --tap postgres_prd_server --target snowflake # Sync every 5 minutes